# Question about Android Tasker variables

Tags: android

Tasker is an app in the app-market that enables one to define simple automation tasks.

I'm writing a task that announces the location coordinates.

However, the location is a built-in variable that is defined to about a dozen decimal places.

I want to round off the value before having it announced.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should use DecimalFormat:

[link text](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Usage example:

double val = 12.4567;
  NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("##0.00");
  String strVal = formatter.format(val);

rounds the double to two decimal places, will output 1 to 3 digits before the decimal place. The above will give you a string of "12.46"